# .NET Core - Trying to add a repository to my API controller, but when I do every controller method returns a 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

As the title says. I'm creating a Web API and in my API controller, I'm trying to declare a repository in the constructor. I successfully declare it, but every API method I try to call in that controller returns a 500 error. When I remove the constructor/repository variable, I have no issues.

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController: Controller
{
   private ITestRepository _testRepository;

   public TestController(ITestRepository testRepository)
   {
       _testRepository= testRepository;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<string> Get()
   {
       return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
   }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Add framework services.
   services
      .AddMvcCore()
      .AddJsonFormatters()
      .AddApiExplorer();

   services.AddScoped<ITestRepository , TestRepository >();    
   services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @CodeNotFound It's just a 500 Internal Server Error. No other info is given. I tried to debug it at the controller level, but the debugger doesn't even reach there before it crashes

Comment: Does your repository class have a parameter less constructor? Show us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

> I'm trying to declare a repository in the constructor. I successfully declare it, but every API method I try to call in that controller returns a 500 error. When I remove the constructor/repository variable, I have no issues.

You probably need to make one of two changes:

1. remove the parameters from the repository's constructor, or
2. register the services that the repository's constructor takes.

## Explanation

The exact code from your question works with the following repository code.

```
public interface ITestRepository { }

public class TestRepository : ITestRepository { }
```

The code throws a 500 error, though, if the constructor takes a parameter.

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(object someObject)
    {

    }
}
```

It throws with that constructor, because a call to `services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>()` requires that the `TestRepository` constructor meets one of these two criteria.

1. a constructor without parameters, or
2. a constructor that takes resolvable services.

So to fix your code you need to make one of two changes:

1. remove the parameters from the constructor, or
2. register the services that your constructor takes.

For instance, if the repository takes a DbContext in its constructor, then your code might look like this.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddApiExplorer();

    services
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddInMemoryDatabase()
        .AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(); // register a service

    services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

**TestRepository.cs**

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    // pass the registered service to the ctor
    public TestRepository(TestDbContext testDbContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First we register the dependent component using Microsoft.practices.Unity, and second we resolve them where we are to use them.

You have not resolved your dependency before using it.

```
public class TestController: Controller
{
    private ITestRepository _testRepository;

    public TestController(ITestRepository testRepository)
    {
        _testRepository= testRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Registering here:

```
DIContainer.Instance.RegisterType<ITagManager, TagManager>();
```

We resolve our dependencies before using them.

```
DIContainer.Instance.Resolve<ITagManager>().RetrieveTwitterTags();
```