# Single Controller, Single Service, multiple repository pattern in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to building web APIs and have reached a point where I could use some direction. 
Lets say for example I have a controller named DocumentController, and a Service named DocumentService which is having implementation of methods of an Interface named IDocumentService. The controller will be using this service. There will be 4-5 repository whose dependency on service should be resolved based upon api call.
These repositories will have different logical implementation of same Interface(say IViewRepository) methods. 
Is there is a way to achieve so? If so, How should I accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of client you have (web, .net etc)?

Comment: Is this (sort of) what you want to accomplish? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573222/autofac-and-mvc-integration-register-type-per-api-controller/27593191#27593191

Comment: @peco : I was looking for something that I found in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443921/how-to-register-service-class-with-multiple-repository-types-in-bootstrapper-fil . Type 2 in this question resolves my issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the link : [How to register service class with multiple repository types in Bootstrapper file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443921/how-to-register-service-class-with-multiple-repository-types-in-bootstrapper-fil).
I had to register the service with a new injection constructor with multiple repositories as its params. 
Line containing the word "Type 2" tells how to register the service the with multiple respositories.

Answer (score 1):

yes, using dependency injection of Microsoft.Practices.Unity; 
for some hint please refer this question [.NET Core - Trying to add a repository to my API controller, but when I do every controller method returns a 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778658/net-core-trying-to-add-a-repository-to-my-api-controller-but-when-i-do-every/36791770#36791770)